# Change the error message for validation

Tags: javascript, magento

I am using following [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/) for displaying validation error messages.

as I am using this : **validate-length** I am getting error message as :

`Text length does not satisfy specified text range` , but I want to change this message as:

"`Zip code is not servicable`"

```
<input placeholder="Enter your PIN Code" class="input-text 
   <?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?>
      required-entry
   <?php endif;?> 

   validate-length maximum-length-6 minimum-length-6 validate-digits"
   type="text"
   id="estimate_postcode"
   name="estimate[postcode]" 
   value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('postcode')) ?>" 
   onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own javascript file:

For example override.js and put it in the js folder of your project.

Then write this code in that override.js file:

```
Validation.add('validate-length', 'Zip code is not servicable')
```

In the layout file you need to add that js file with the addJs method:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>override.js</script></action>
```

Comment: i will try this & let you know.